# How to close two model pop ups at time in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

1. I am in first model popup.
2. on click of proceed, I am moving to second popup.
3. after click on save from second popup, on success, I need to close two popups at a time.

can any one please suggest

Comment: any body have solution for my problem?

Comment: What are you using for your modals?  Some third party library?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the result of the second popup as a kind of promise on the first one

Are they in diferent scopes? 
Are you using some library?

Can you show us some code, for example when you call the second popup

Comment: This issue I fixed by using the $rootScope.$emit

Comment: Ok, but have in mind that broadcast, and emit are a little dangerous if we don't know how to control their propagation, It's better, for me, to use services and promises to control the flow of your system.